# remove one charachter from a speficic column in df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column that some values are having `...` and some `..` and some are without dots.

```
 Type    range
    Mike    10..13
    Ni      3..4
    NANA    2...3
    Gi      2
```

desired output should look like this

```
Type    range
Mike    10
Mike    11
Mike    12
MIke    13    
Ni      3
Ni      4
NANA    2
NANA    3
Gi      2
```

So dots represnt the range of between to number ( inclusive the end number).

How am I suppsoed to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse str as list first and then [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import re
def str_to_list(s):
    if not s: return []
    nums = re.split('\.{2,3}', s)
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums
    return list(range(int(nums[0]), int(nums[1]) + 1))

df['range'] = df['range'].astype(str).map(str_to_list)
df.explode('range')

   Type range
0  Mike    10
0  Mike    11
0  Mike    12
0  Mike    13
1    Ni     3
1    Ni     4
2  NANA     2
2  NANA     3
3    Gi     2
```

Comment: gives me the error `nums = re.split('\.{2,3}', s)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\re.py", line 230, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: You might have some numbers in `range` column, try `.astype(str)` first -

Answer (score 0):

An approach using [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .assign(range=
                          df["range"]
                            .str.replace("\.+", "-", regex=True)
                            .str.split("-")
                            .apply(lambda x: np.arange(list(map(int, x))[0], list(map(int, x))[-1]+1, 1) if len(x)>1 else x))
          .explode("range", ignore_index=True)
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   Type range
0  Mike    10
1  Mike    11
2  Mike    12
3  Mike    13
4    Ni     3
5    Ni     4
6  NANA     2
7  NANA     3
8    Gi     2
```